# How to split data in ratio using SQL

Tags: sql, database

Suppose we have a table with columns X and Y where Y is the total count of values present in X.

| Column X | Column Y |
| --- | --- |
| 3000 | 23 |
| 8000 | 50 |
| 4000 | 20 |
| 9000 | 70 |
| 5000 | 64 |

How to split the data with 8:1:1 ratio of column Y.

Example: Y is 23. Therefore 8:1:1 of Y will be nearly 18,2,3. There will be 18 rows for train, 3 rows for test and 2 rows for val.

Similarly 8:1:1 of 64 will be 51,7 and 6.

Expected output table is like this:

| Column X | Column Y | Column Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3000 | 1 | Train |
| 3000 | . | Train |
| 3000 | . | Train |
| 3000 | 18 | Train |
| 3000 | 1 | Test |
| 3000 | . | Test |
| 3000 | 3 | Test |
| 3000 | 1 | Val |
| 3000 | 2 | Val |
| 8000 | 1 | Train |
| 8000 | . | Train |
| 8000 | 40 | Train |
| 8000 | 1 | Test |
| 8000 | . | Test |
| 8000 | 5 | Test |
| 8000 | 1 | Val |
| 8000 | . | Val |
| 8000 | 5 | Val |
| 4000 | 1 | Train |
| 4000 | . | Train |
| 4000 | . | Train |
| 4000 | 16 | Train |
| 4000 | 1 | Test |
| 4000 | 2 | Test |
| 4000 | 1 | Val |
| 4000 | 2 | Val |
| 5000 | 1 | Train |
| 5000 | . | Train |
| 5000 | 51 | Train |
| 5000 | 1 | Test |
| 5000 | . | Test |
| 5000 | . | Test |
| 5000 | 7 | Test |
| 5000 | 1 | Val |
| 5000 | . | Val |
| 5000 | 6 | Val |

To summarize, I want to split the all rows in train, test, val set in proportion of 8:1:1 using column Y value.

I tried using Pandas for similar task, but unable to do it in SQL

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question earlier today? How have you improved your question this time?

Comment: SQL is the wrong tool to attempt this kind of task (unless you have no other choice and can afford to deal with a convoluted query). Any other pandas solution would be much more preferable.

Comment: How would you know to put a period in ColumnY?

Comment: @dougp It's not a period. there will be value in there. Eg. for 3000, there will be 18 rows for train.

Comment: @lemon Yes. I am able to do that in Pandas. But specifically want to do this in SQL as the dataset is huge and I am unable to do that in Python. Not sure if we can use rank for each value of column X. eg., for all 3000 number we can rank and then split that in 8:1:1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force method that will work.  I had to make an assumption on what you mean by 8:1:1, but result in integers:

Val8 = FLOOR(ColumnY * 0.8)
Val1a = FLOOR(ColumnY * 0.1)
Val1b = ColumnY - Val8 - Val1a

So, you may need to adjust if you have clearer requirements.

The code below is written for SQL Server.  Among other possible differences, other RDBMSs (like Oracle) may require `WITH RECURSIVE` for the recursive CTE to process without error.

```
with a as (
  select *
  from (
    values (1, 3000, 23)
         , (2, 8000, 50)
         , (3, 4000, 20)
         , (4, 9000, 70)
         , (5, 5000, 64)
  ) t (id, ColumnX, ColumnY)
),
b as (
  select id
  , 'Train' as ColumnZ
  , ColumnX
  , cast(ColumnY * 0.8 as int) as ColumnY
  from a
  union all
  select id
  , 'Test' as ColumnZ
  , ColumnX
  , cast(ColumnY * 0.1 as int) as ColumnY
  from a
),
c as (
  select b.id
  , 'Val' as ColumnZ
  , b.ColumnX
  , a.ColumnY - sum(b.ColumnY) as ColumnY
  from b
    inner join a on a.ColumnX = b.ColumnX
  group by b.id
  , b.ColumnX
  , a.ColumnY
),
iterator as (
  select 1 as ColumnY
  , max(ColumnY) as m
  from c
  union all
  select ColumnY + 1
  , m
  from iterator
  where ColumnY <= m
)
select b.ColumnX
, i.ColumnY
, b.ColumnZ
from b
  inner join iterator i on i.ColumnY <= b.ColumnY
union all
select c.ColumnX
, i.ColumnY
, c.ColumnZ
from c
  inner join iterator i on i.ColumnY <= c.ColumnY
order by 1, 3, 2
```

Comment: Hi, here in iterator, you are selecting from iterator. Isn't that an error?

Comment: I updated my answer.  It would be helpful if you would add appropriate tags to your question.